# nodejs cluster workers optimization

Tags: node.js, optimization, server, node-cluster

Let's say I have a 12 core CPU on which I am running a nodejs application. 
 
The application mainly does two things - 
1. Convert uploaded video from one format to another (CPU intensive) 
2. Serve other DB intensive GET/POST requests 
 
Question: Is it best to create 2 servers - one for CPU work, another for DB work? If I use cluster module, how many workers should I spawn on each server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not have transcoding on the same server as the REST api server, but rather offload it to a separate server.

There are many services that provide transcoding capabilities such as [Amazon Elastic Transcoder](https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/) or others. If you insist on having your own server, then I would use a [Docker container around FFMPEG](https://hub.docker.com/r/cellofellow/ffmpeg/) and spin that up within a Docker auto-scaling environment like [Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/)

Comment: Is it a problem to accomplish transcoding using FFMPEG on a separate server running on the same machine as the REST API server (I am not very inclined to use AWS)?

Comment: Transcoding uses more than just CPU and would cause many problems to your rest API if you tried to run it on the same machine. It would also gobble up RAM and other resources. I would really recommend keeping it on a separate machine entirely. There are other services besides AWS that provide transcoding as a service.